# Issue sending & receiving streams between two clients in LiveKit's React Native SDK

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I'm trying to build on the example app provided by livekit, so far I've implemented everything like the example app and I've been successful with connecting to a room on [example website](https://example.livekit.io/), I recieve audio from website, but I don't read the video stream, and I also can't send audio or video at all.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. add the following to `index.js`

```
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import { registerGlobals } from "livekit-react-native";

import App from "./App";
registerRootComponent(App);
registerGlobals();
```

3. Rendering the following component in `App.tsx`

```
import { Participant, Room, Track } from "livekit-client";
import {
  useRoom,
  useParticipant,
  AudioSession,
  VideoView,
} from "livekit-react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, ListRenderItem, StyleSheet, FlatList, View } from "react-native";
import { ParticipantView } from "./ParticipantView";
import { RoomControls } from "./RoomControls";
import type { TrackPublication } from "livekit-client";

const App = () => {
  // Create a room state
  const [, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const [room] = useState(
    () =>
      new Room({
        publishDefaults: { simulcast: false },
        adaptiveStream: true,
      })
  );

  // Get the participants from the room
  const { participants } = useRoom(room);
  const url = "[hard-coded-url]";
  const token =
    "[hard-coded-token";
  useEffect(() => {
    let connect = async () => {
      // If you wish to configure audio, uncomment the following:
      await AudioSession.configureAudio({
        android: {
          preferredOutputList: ["speaker"],
        },
        ios: {
          defaultOutput: "speaker",
        },
      });
      await AudioSession.startAudioSession();
      await room.connect(url, token, {});
      await room.localParticipant.setCameraEnabled(true);
      await room.localParticipant.setMicrophoneEnabled(true);
      await room.localParticipant.enableCameraAndMicrophone();
      console.log("connected to ", url);
      setIsConnected(true);
    };

    connect();
    return () => {
      room.disconnect();
      AudioSession.stopAudioSession();
    };
  }, [url, token, room]);
  // Setup views.
  const stageView = participants.length > 0 && (
    <ParticipantView participant={participants[0]} style={styles.stage} />
  );

  const renderParticipant: ListRenderItem<Participant> = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <ParticipantView participant={item} style={styles.otherParticipantView} />
    );
  };

  const otherParticipantsView = participants.length > 0 && (
    <FlatList
      data={participants}
      renderItem={renderParticipant}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.sid}
      horizontal={true}
      style={styles.otherParticipantsList}
    />
  );

  const { cameraPublication, microphonePublication } = useParticipant(
    room.localParticipant
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {stageView}
      {otherParticipantsView}
      <RoomControls
        micEnabled={isTrackEnabled(microphonePublication)}
        setMicEnabled={(enabled: boolean) => {
          room.localParticipant.setMicrophoneEnabled(enabled);
        }}
        cameraEnabled={isTrackEnabled(cameraPublication)}
        setCameraEnabled={(enabled: boolean) => {
          room.localParticipant.setCameraEnabled(enabled);
        }}
        onDisconnectClick={() => {
          //   navigation.pop();
          console.log("disconnected");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

function isTrackEnabled(pub?: TrackPublication): boolean {
  return !(pub?.isMuted ?? true);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  stage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
  },
  otherParticipantsList: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 150,
    flexGrow: 0,
  },
  otherParticipantView: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },
});

export default App;
```

the components used here are mostly the same as what's in the example, I've removed the screensharing logic and the messages
5. I run the app using an expo development build
6. it will log that it's connected, you'll be able to hear sound from the remote participant, but not see any video or send any sound.
7. if i try to add
`await room.localParticipant.enableCameraAndMicrophone();`
in the `useEffect`, I get the following error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Not implemented.
getSettings@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:103733:24
@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:120307:109
generatorResume@[native code]
asyncGeneratorStep@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21908:26
_next@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21927:29
@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21932:14
tryCallTwo@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:26656:9
doResolve@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:26788:25
Promise@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:26675:14
@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21924:25
@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:120173:52
generatorResume@[native code]
asyncGeneratorStep@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21908:26
_next@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21927:29
tryCallOne@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:26648:16
@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:26729:27
@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27687:26
_callTimer@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27602:17
_callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27635:17
callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27799:44
__callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21006:46
@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:20806:45
__guard@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:20986:15
flushedQueue@http://192.168.1.150:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:20805:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
```

**Expected behavior**
This should both receive & send video and audio streams between the two clients